# Displaying orbits on ground track map using TLE lines

Tags: javascript

I am trying to draw an orbit on a ground track map using TLE lines like this using JS:

```
1 45657U 20035A   20196.59974008  .38210219  12083-4  47903-3 0  9997
2 45657  53.0001 319.7129 0028054 181.2741 293.9291 16.46735707  7405
```

```
var attribution =
  'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
var tile = "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";


var tle_Pos = getPosVel();
var longitude = tle_Pos.longitude
var latitude = tle_Pos.latitude
var worldMap = drawMap();
var objectDrawer = drawObject();


function getPosVel(){
  var tleLine1 = '1 45657U 20035A   20196.59974008  .38210219  12083-4  47903-3 0  9997',
      tleLine2 = '2 45657  53.0001 319.7129 0028054 181.2741 293.9291 16.46735707  7405';



  var gmst = satellite.gstime(new Date());
  var satrec = satellite.twoline2satrec(tleLine1, tleLine2);

  var positionAndVelocity = satellite.propagate(satrec, new Date());

  var gmst = satellite.gstime(new Date());

  var geodeticCoords = satellite.eciToGeodetic(positionAndVelocity.position, gmst);
  console.log(geodeticCoords);

  return geodeticCoords
}


function drawMap() {
  var map = L.map("mapid").setView([0, 0], 4);
    L.tileLayer(tile, {
      maxZoom: 25,
      minZoom: 1.8,
      attribution: attribution
    }).addTo(map);
    return map;
}


function drawObject() {
  return L.marker([longitude, latitude]).addTo(worldMap);
}
```

I have tried to use satellite.js and Leaflet map but I ran into couple of problems doing this, First thing I cant figure how to predict and draw the orbit and not only the object's current latitude and longitude, Secondly, when I provide the TLE lines below it doesnt work at all, and when I provided the regular ISS TLE lines it worked but I dont think the latitude and longitude are accurate at all.

Is there anything alternative to use other than satellite.js or is there a right way to draw the full orbit of the TLE lines?

EXTRA: Here is an [image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/rRSpwnXUjnyK8IcW0szu9s7KP0Xdro7K62hd5jecu1VHzRNy-BQlE5WBWb42UcFw10Lu_CZCnIKtVeGInZx5k0KCqVM4pm_Vme1h-eI) of how I want the map to look like.

Comment: I cannot open your image link. Also try to create a working example in JSFiddle or similar websites